# Getting return type of Task (not Task<T>)

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity-2, .net-4.6.2

I use ASP.NET Identity 2.2.1.

I implement the interface `IIdentityMessageService` like this:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        string body = ONMailStyles.getOpening();
        body += message.Body;
        Mail mailService = new Mail(message.Destination, message.Subject, body);
        string succes = mailService.send();
        return Task.FromResult(succes);
    }
}
```

Below is (a part) of my Mail class:

```
public class Mail
{
    public MailMessage message { get; set; }
    public string send(string host, int port, string username, string wachtwoord, int timeout)
    {
        SmtpClient ss = new SmtpClient(host, port);
        ss.EnableSsl = true;
        ss.Timeout = timeout;
        ss.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        ss.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        ss.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, wachtwoord);
        try
        {
            ss.Send(message);
            message.Dispose();
            return "succes";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "no succes: " + ex.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

In one of my controller's I have the following line:

```
var emailResult = UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Activeer uw lichtmeting account.", htmlMessage);
```

I get a result back of type `Task`. If I had `await` a like this I expected to get the string result of `succes`:

```
var emailResult = await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Activeer uw lichtmeting account.", htmlMessage);
```

But I get the following compile error: "cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable". I just want to get the result of `success` in my controller. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the interface method and create your own method to use from the outside:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    Task IIdentityMessageService.SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        return this.SendAsync(message);
    }

    public Task<string> SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        string body = ONMailStyles.getOpening();
        body += message.Body;
        Mail mailService = new Mail(message.Destination, message.Subject, body);
        string succes = mailService.send();
        return Task.FromResult(succes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried you're solution, but still don't get it to work. Notice I call `SendEmailAsync` in my controller and not `SendAsync`. I my UserManager class I call `manager.EmailService = new EmailService();`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an await in your SendAsync method - is it actually calling anything asynchronously? Also if you want it to return a string you should make it return `Task<string>`, not Task. I'd try something along these lines.

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task<string> SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        string body = ONMailStyles.getOpening();
        body += message.Body;
        var mailService = new Mail(message.Destination, message.Subject, body);
        string success = await mailService.send();
        return success;
    }
}
```

Comment: My own created `mailService`(`Mail` class) does not have an async method. Can't I put in a fake await or something in the SendAsync method above. Otheriwise I have to create an async method in my Mail class

Comment: If you are not calling any async methods there is no point in using Tasks and await, you should just use standard synchronous code.